# Is it possible to detect completion of a parent modalview dismiss animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller

ViewController -> ModalViewController1 ---horizontalflip ---> ModalViewController2

So when 'Done' is touched in MVC2 to dismiss itself + a delegate method is called in MVC1 which does some stuff and then dismisses itself.

Problem is that this 'stuff' is already done before the animation dismissing MVC2 is complete.
I'd like to be able to check when the animation is complete then dismiss MVC1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC1 should receive a viewDidAppear once the animation of MVC2 is done. You could do the "stuff" in there, based on a condition set by the delegate call you're already doing.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but wasn't sure doing it that way was acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use delegate to achieve this.

In MVC2.h

```
@protocal MVC2Delegate <NSObject>
@optional
  - (void) doneShowing;
@end
```

In MVC2.m, you can implement a IBAction method when you tap "Done", call doneShowing inside the action.

In MVC1, you can implement this delegate method, do whatever you wanna do inside it, lastly, call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>]`